# Number of Non-Isomorphic Subgroups of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am relatively new to abstract algebra, and am having trouble solving this problem.
How would I go about finding all these subgroups that are not isomorphic to a permutation group of 3? So far I only know that these subgroups are of an order that divides 6, and must include the identity mapping element.
Is it true that if $f,g, i \in s_3$, where $s_3$ is a subgroup of the permutation group $S_3$, and $f \circ f = g$, then $s_3$ isn't isomorphic to $S_3$ since $f \circ f = g$ and $g \circ i = g$ ? Or is that completely false since $i$ is the identity mapping. Sorry if that makes little sense. Thank you for any help.

Comment: "non-isomorphic subgroups" here probably means "pairwise not isomorphic" (not "not isomorphic with $S_3$").

Comment: Identity forms a unique subgroup. Any reflection (e.g (12)) has order 2 and so generates a cyclic group of order 2. The element (123) generates a cyclic subgroup of order 3. Any other subgroup which is not the whole group is isomorphic to one of these.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use Lagrange's Theorem. Every subgroup of $S_3$ must have order dividing $6$. So, the possible orders of subgroups of $S_3$ are $1,2,3,6$. There is a unique subgroup of order $6$, namely $S_3$. The identity is the unique subgroup of order $1$. Since $2$ and $3$ are prime, any group with either of these orders is isomorphic to the cyclic group of the appropriate order. So, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are the other possible subgroups up to isomorphism. Each of these subgroups occurs, since we can take the cyclic subgroup generated by a transposition, and the cyclic subgroup generated by a three-cycle.

Just to add, the subgroups of order $2$ are precisely those generated by the transpositions. These are $\{e,(12)\}$, $\{e,(13)\}$, and $\{e,(23)\}$. The subgroups of order $3$ are those generated by $3$-cycles. There is just one of these, namely $\{e,(123),(132)\}$.

Comment: I thought subgroups of $S_3$ needed to have elements of "size" 3. For example, $\{e,(12)\}$ seems to have two mappings of only two elements. Is it because if they had mapped more than two elements, it would not be of order 2?

Comment: $(12)$ really means $(12)(3)$. We suppress any fixed points.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Alright, so with this I can generate all possible subgroups. But how do I find out which are not isomorphic to $S_3$, and how much are not? They should all be homomorphic to $S_3$, right?

Comment: The only subgroup of $S_3$ isomorphic to $S_3$ is $S_3$ itself. The reason is that such a subgroup would consist of $6$ elements, but there are only $6$ elements in $S_3$. So, each of the subgroups not equal to $S_3$ is not isomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. I was just overlooking that basic fact since I got caught up in finding $S_3$'s subgroups. Thank you for your help!